# Multiple set-cookies in header rewrites each other curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

If response header contains two `Set-Cookie` value as in the example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=***; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2020 15:26:07 GMT
Content-Length: 14713
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerauto-ext-vla216-pool=***; path=/; Httponly
```

,then with parameters

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
```

cUrl will write to file only the last, because of overwriting.

Is there a better way then manually read header and write to file via `file_put_contents`, to store multiple cookies for this case?

Comment: `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` is where curl *reads* from. `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` is the file curl *writes* cookies to

Comment: @DanielStenberg so what?

Comment: So I don't understand the question.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I need to store both cookies from header how to do that?

Comment: `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` does that

Comment: @DanielStenberg all yesterday it didn’t but now does. How did You do that magic? Seems I need to sleep more, but it 100% saved only the last...

Answer (score 0):

Curl does accept cookies from different `Set-Cookie` headers.

Take a look at the documentation:

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.html

> CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE - file name to read cookies from

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.html

> CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR - file name to store cookies to

Comment: *Curl does accept cookies from different `Set-Cookie` headers.* Didn’t find anything about that in the documentation You have mentioned

Comment: @Artur the documentation is only informing that the cookiejar is the only file that should be written to. Curl accepts multiple Set-Cookie headers because that's the default behavior. I can't reproduce any example of where it fails to do that.

Comment: Why would it document that? It documents that you enable the cookie engine and then it will understand and use cookies. That of course includes handling a large amount of them.